# How to create WHERE condition with tuples

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to check if a tuple is in selected rows.

I have a **user** such as the next (simplified):

```
user_id int,
company_id,
subcompany_id
```

and **org_cat** model such as next one:

```
cat_id,
company_id,
subcompany_id
```

I'd like to select user ids for all users which are in the category with cat_id=2.

The next is wrong:

```
SELECT 
    user_id 
FROM "user" 
WHERE 
    company_id IN ( SELECT company_id FROM org_cat where cat_id=2 )
AND
    subcompany_id IN ( SELECT subcompany_id FROM org_cat where cat_id=2 );
```

because if we have combinations { 1, 3 }, { 2, 3 }, { 3, 3 } (in companies as company_id, subcompany_id and company_id=1, subcompany_id=3 in org_cat with cat_id=2 **then all rows will be selected from user** - that's incorrect.

I mean the next query which interpreps wrong for me:

```
SELECT 
    user_id 
FROM "user" 
WHERE 
    ( company_id, subcompany_id ) IN ( SELECT company_id, subcompany_id FROM org_cat where cat_id=2 );
```

because postgresql probably does not think that ( company_id, subcompany_id ) is tuple.

Could you help to construct a correct query please?

**Update**.

Indeed the variant with "( company_id, subcompany_id ) IN..." is valid too but little slower then the answer. Thank you, **a_horse_with_no_name**!

Comment: "*because Postgres probably does not think that ... is a tuple*" - why do you think that? That query will work just fine: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/062e7/4

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Indeed! Slowdown in my brain...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id
FROM "user" U join org_cat on U.company_id = org_cat.company_id 
AND U.subcompany_id = org_cat.subcompany_id 
WHERE org_cat.cat_id = 2
```

SQL Fiddle: [click here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/062e7/1)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just concatenate the values in your tuples:

```
WHERE CAST(company_Id as VARCHAR) + '|' + CAST(subcompany_id as VARCHAR) IN 
    (SELECT CAST(company_Id as VARCHAR) + '|' + CAST(subcompany_id as VARCHAR) FROM ... )
```

Comment: Probably a good idea. But I think that with JOIN is more stylishly.

Comment: That's invalid SQL. Strings are concatenated using `||` not using `+` in SQL. And if it were a correct SQL, that approach would prevent the use of indexes on those columns.

Comment: SQL is valid, I agree with your remark regarding the usage of the indexes. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Dd2, no, that SQL is *not* valid in Postgresql. Did you try it before posting?